# Installing a php extension (xdiff) from pecl on Linux

Tags: php, linux, command, installation, pecl

I was getting this error on my php script:

`Fatal error:  Call to undefined function xdiff_file_diff()`

I realised that I didn't had the xdiff extension installed. When I tried to install it using the **install pecl xdiff** command, I got this errors (among other lines):

> configure: WARNING: You will need re2c
>   0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP 
>       configure: error: Please reinstall the libxdiff distribution

Then I installed **re2c** and **libxdiff**:

```
wget http://www.compdigitec.com/labs/files/re2c_0135_redhat.rpm
wget ftp://ftp.task.gda.pl/vol/vol1/ftp.pld-linux.org/dists/2.0/PLD/i386/PLD/RPMS/libxdiff-0.7-1.i386.rpm
rpm -ivh re2c_0135_redhat.rpm
rpm -ivh libxdiff-0.7-1.i386
```

But after that I still get the same errors.

PS: I've Googled a LOT and I found a couple of people with this problem but they didn't get an answer either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can occur if your are using wrong parameters or installation is file is corrupted.

You can refer to the following URL for more details regarding function `xdiff_file_diff()`:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.xdiff-file-diff.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/ref.xdiff.php